# Google analytics unknown route

Tags: google-analytics, routes

I have google analytics for my site, and I noticed a visit on the page "/vbly.us/3835". 
I have no idea what that route is, and my site is supposed to redirect to welcome page if route is not found. What could this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just analytics spam for the benefit of the web admins reading the logs, or possibly other relevant parties who may be getting e-mailed reports that include such data. Such spam is not uncommon and you can filter it out in your settings to omit spam data from your reports. You probably also got hit by "/www.JSMiningStatistics.com" and possibly some other "/www.tinyurl.com" links. They use short URLs to get around filters or blocks that might be in place against them for spamming already, and they hop around different short URL providers as their short URLs get terminated for violating the terms of use agreements of the short URL providers. You can google search "google analytics spam bots" for more info.

Basically spammers use bots to spam the Google Analytics service and it works whether your site is online or offline because it has to do with communicating with Google Analytics and not your site. When you use Google Analytics, anyone can send you fake data by only knowing that ID number you put into all your Google Analytics scripts on your site. Your ID can either be scraped by a bot right off your site or randomly brute forced by a bot simply iterating through the IDs in numerical order or randomly without any knowledge of your site at all.

Answer (score 2):

Did you test your website on a localhost server?

Comment: Hmm no, analytics are off on my local environment, and definitely I did not use it while this visit was registered.